# $\forall k \in \mathbb{N},n^n \notin O(n^k)$

Tags: proof-verification, asymptotics

$\forall k \in \mathbb{N},n^n \notin O(n^k)$

Show $\forall k \in \mathbb{N},\forall c,n_0 \in \mathbb{R^+},\exists n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq n_0 \wedge n^n\ > cn^k$

Proof.

let $k \in \mathbb{N}, c,n_0 \in \mathbb{R^+},n= {\lceil}max\{c,k,n_0\}{\rceil}+1$

Case1:$n= {\lceil}c{\rceil}+1$

Show $( {\lceil}c{\rceil}+1)^{ {\lceil}c{\rceil}+1}>c( {\lceil}c{\rceil}+1)^k$

Since $c>k$

That $ {\lceil}c{\rceil}>k$

Have $ {\lceil}c{\rceil}-k>0$

Add one to both side have $ {\lceil}c{\rceil}-k+1>1$

Therefore $( {\lceil}c{\rceil}+1)^{ {\lceil}c{\rceil}+1-k}> {\lceil}c{\rceil}+1>c$

That $( {\lceil}c{\rceil}+1)^{ {\lceil}c{\rceil}+1-k}( {\lceil}c{\rceil}+1)^k>c( {\lceil}c{\rceil}+1)^k$

Have $n^n>cn^k$ hold

Case2:$n= {\lceil}k{\rceil}+1$

Show $( {\lceil}k{\rceil}+1)^{ {\lceil}k{\rceil}+1}>c( {\lceil}k{\rceil}+1)^k$

Same as $( {\lceil}k{\rceil}+1)( {\lceil}k{\rceil}+1)^{k}>c( {\lceil}k{\rceil}+1)^k$

Since $k>c \wedge  {\lceil}k{\rceil}+1>k$

That $ {\lceil}k{\rceil}+1>c$

Have $n^n>cn^k$ hold

Case3:$n= {\lceil}n_0{\rceil}+1$

Show $( {\lceil}n_0{\rceil}+1)^{ {\lceil}n_0{\rceil}+1}>c( {\lceil}n_0{\rceil}+1)^k$

Since $n_0>k \wedge  {\lceil}n_0{\rceil} \geq n_0$
   That $ {\lceil}n_0{\rceil} > k$

Have $ {\lceil}n_0{\rceil}-k>0$

Add one to both side have $ {\lceil}n_0{\rceil}-k+1>1$

Therefore $( {\lceil}n_0{\rceil}+1)^{ {\lceil}n_0{\rceil}+1-k}> {\lceil}n_0{\rceil}+1>c$

That $( {\lceil}n_0{\rceil}+1)^{ {\lceil}n_0{\rceil}+1-k}( {\lceil}n_0{\rceil}+1)^k>c( {\lceil}n_0{\rceil}+1)^k$

Have $n^n>cn^k$ hold

Q.E.D

Comment: I don't know what $c$ is doing inside $O$, but show the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want a proof using the algebraic definition, in which case, for all $k\in\Bbb N$ and $c,n_0\in\Bbb R^+$, choose $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\gt\max\{k,n_0,c\}$, then for some $m\geq 1$, we have $$n^n=n^m\cdot n^k\gt cn^k$$

since $n^m\gt c$ as $n^m\geq n^1\gt c$.

---

The proof in the other answer is equivalent by the limit definition of Big-O notation.

Comment: yes, need to find some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and show the inequality hold

Comment: @subcatgory: I don't understand your comment. I did exactly that in my answer. There always will exist some $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\gt\max\{k,n_0,c\}$ since by construction of $\Bbb N$, there is no greatest natural number.

Comment: yea, that make sense

Answer (score 0):

As for all constant $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^k}{n^n} = 0$, $n^n \not\in O(n^k)$ for all constant $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: With $\infty$ you mean $0$, right?

Comment: @Wojowu yes. right.

Comment: @subcatgory it's the definition of the asymptotic notation $O$. What do you mean?

Comment: That right, but is $\infty \in \mathbb{N}$, i mean can we find a value for n based on $c,k,n_0$ and prove it hold

Comment: $\infty $ is not a number, maybe need to find a exact value for n in this proof?

Comment: @subcatgory this is the definition of limit! you can set $c = 1$, $n_0 = k+1$.

Comment: to disprove it, we need to show it hold for all $c,k,n_0$, but only pick a value for n, i guess